# cvxpy - How to obtain the variable value after each iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, cvxpy, cvx

I am using cvxpy to solve a second order cone program. I have used the boilerplate code as mentioned in the cvxpy website - [cvxpy SOCP webpage](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/socp.html). I do not know how to obtain the variable value after each iteration...

Code from the link:

```py
# Import packages.
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate a random feasible SOCP.
m = 3
n = 10
p = 5
n_i = 5
f = np.random.randn(n)
A = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
x0 = np.random.randn(n)
for i in range(m):
    A.append(np.random.randn(n_i, n))
    b.append(np.random.randn(n_i))
    c.append(np.random.randn(n))
    d.append(np.linalg.norm(A[i] @ x0 + b, 2) - c[i].T @ x0)

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
x = cp.Variable(n)
# We use cp.SOC(t, x) to create the SOC constraint ||x||_2 <= t.
soc_constraints = [
      cp.SOC(c[i].T @ x + d[i], A[i] @ x + b[i]) for i in range(m)
]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(f.T@x), soc_constraints)
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(x.value)
```

`x.value` here only gives the variable value after all the iterations are done. I want `x.value` after each iteration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.