# How can I access the cost at each iteration when using the solve function in the cvxpy library?

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

If you want to solve a convex optimization problem using the `cvxpy` library, only the last iteration cost can be calculated and returned, while other intermediate costs and related values are printed during the process. Take a look at the following code, which is obtained from the [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#viewing-solver-output) library itself:

```
import cvxpy

x = cvxpy.Variable(2)
objective = cvxpy.Minimize(x[0] + cvxpy.norm(x, 1))
constraints = [x >= 2]
problem = cvxpy.Problem(objective, constraints)

problem.solve(solver=cvxpy.ECOS, verbose=True)
```

And the printed result:

```
ECOS 2.0.10 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +6.667e-01  +7.067e-01  +6e+00  6e-01  1e-02  1e+00  9e-01    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  - 
 1  +3.500e+00  +3.925e+00  +1e+00  3e-01  4e-03  8e-01  2e-01  0.9890  2e-01   1  1  1 |  0  0
 2  +5.716e+00  +5.825e+00  +2e-01  6e-02  8e-04  2e-01  4e-02  0.9091  8e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0
 3  +5.997e+00  +5.998e+00  +3e-03  7e-04  1e-05  2e-03  5e-04  0.9881  1e-04   1  1  1 |  0  0
 4  +6.000e+00  +6.000e+00  +3e-05  8e-06  1e-07  3e-05  5e-06  0.9890  1e-04   1  1  1 |  0  0
 5  +6.000e+00  +6.000e+00  +3e-07  9e-08  1e-09  3e-07  6e-08  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0
 6  +6.000e+00  +6.000e+00  +4e-09  1e-09  1e-11  3e-09  6e-10  0.9890  1e-04   1  0  0 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=9.9e-10, reltol=6.2e-10, abstol=3.7e-09).
Runtime: 0.000061 seconds.
```

We can only evaluate the final cost value of the last iteration using the `objective.value` or `problem.value`.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71692428/cvxpy-how-to-obtain-the-variable-value-after-each-iteration) but I don't need the other variables, I only need the costs which are printed by the library itself.

Comment: Some solvers can provide it through a callback function, but then you would have to use the solver's interface directly, or add that to your cvxpy source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an extensive search through `cvxpy` internals, I discovered that it utilizes an underlying library (such as [ecos](https://github.com/embotech/ecos)) for solving, but unfortunately, it lacks any data on the intermediate iterations. I also confirmed that the printed log is generated by the underlying library and not by `cvxpy` itself. Subsequently, my investigation of the `ecos` library revealed that it also does not store the intermediate information. Instead, it maintains a simple `info` struct that gets updated after each iteration.

Finally, I made the decision to capture the output stream and subsequently parse the result using the regex to extract the required information. I am aware that this approach is somewhat tricky and fragile, but it effectively solves my problem:

```
import re

import cvxpy
import wurlitzer

# The convex problem definition ...

with wurlitzer.pipes() as (out, err):
    problem.solve(solver=cvxpy.ECOS, verbose=True)

matches = re.findall(
    "^\s*(?P<iteration>\d+)\s+(?P<pcost>\S+)\s+.*$",
    out.getvalue(),
    re.MULTILINE
)

data = []
for iteration, pcost in matches:
    data.append(float(pcost))

print(data)
```

And I get:

```
[0.6667, 3.5, 5.716, 5.997, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0]
```

I only need the `pcost` value, but feel free to improve the regex pattern to suit your specific requirements.

I had to use [wurlitzer](https://pypi.org/project/wurlitzer/) because the table is printed at the C-level, and the common approaches, such as `contextlib.redirect_stdout`, cannot be used.